# How to save files into external storage with scoped storage since Android Q while compatible with older api level in android?

Tags: android, android-10.0

With scoped storage coming with Android Q, we can only create or access shareable files in external storage with MediaStore api or SAF.
However, according to my experiment result, relative paths and display names won't work even if specified when I trying to insert a ContentValues object with MediaStore api on platforms below Android Q (like the code below), which makes this api not fully functional.

```
contentResolver.insert(externalUri, ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "${prefix}_${datetimeString}.jpg")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
})
```

On the other hand, I don't think I should use SAF, since it's quite annoying to make users choose a location to save a media file every time.
Another possible approach would be to fallback to Environment.getexternalstoragedirectory, but this method is reported to be deprecated by the IDE even if I've checked api level in my code. So I think this may not be recommended.
Is there a better way to save a shareable media file (into specified location with a specified name), while compatible with older api level?

Comment: Below Android Q you should not use RELATIVE_PATH but DATA. And a full path.

Comment: `I should use SAF, since it's quite annoying to make users choose a location to save a media file every time.` You only have to let the user choose once a directory which you then can use to save your files in. Only once.

Comment: `Another possible approach would be to fallback to Environment.getexternalstoragedirectory,`. No. That even is not possible anymore. Thats the whole point.

Comment: @blackapps I know that getExternalStorageDirectory is not working on Android Q, but will it still not work if it's run on older platforms and api level is checked appropriately?     
Besides, should I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE instead of ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT to make users only choose once?

Comment: On below Q it will work. Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE  to select a directory only once. After that you can write as many files in that directory as you want. Your life long. With ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT you invoke the user for every file.

Comment: But of course you can let the MediaStore provide you with an uri for a file on external storage where you want to write content to (in special directories only) . No user interaction needed. No permissions needed on Q.